# Comparing a datetime dataframe with a period dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have been stuck with a simple **pandas dataframe problem** and maybe someone faced this situation before...

Thank you in advance :)

Hi have two dataframes, df1 and df2:

df1

```
unique_id    timestamp
1            2019-01-21
2            2019-02-01
3            2019-04-05
4            2019-05-01
5            2019-05-12
...          ...
```

df2

```
classification     from            to
A                  2019-01-05      2019-02-02
B                  2019-02-03      2019-02-28
C                  2019-03-01      2019-04-05
D                  2019-04-06      2019-05-03
E                  2019-05-04      2019-05-31
...                ...             ...
```

My goal is to compare each **timestamp** in df1 with each **from** **to** date interval in df2 and be able to classify every **unique_id** of df1 with the correspondent **classification** of df2

I was trying something like this:

```
df1.loc[(df1['timestamp'] > df2['from]) & (df1['timestamp'] < df2['to']), 'class'] = df2['classification']´
```

always get a **ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects** despite both datetime dtypes are the exact same, **datetime64[ns]**...

**Expected Output**:

```
unique_id         timestamp        classification
1                 2019-01-21       A
2                 2019-02-01       A
3                 2019-04-05       C
4                 2019-05-01       D
5                 2019-05-12       E
...               ...              ...
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output you want on this sample ?

Comment: I updated the question with the *expected output*. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the index of the both dataframe. With this syntax you're suggesting, comparison is done **row by row**. You can just see it if we condisere the following dataframes (with different size):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, "2019-01-21"],
    [2, "2019-02-01"],
    [3, "2019-04-05"],
    [4, "2019-04-05"],
    [5, "2019-04-05"],
    [6, "2019-04-05"],
    [7, "2019-05-01"],
    [8, "2019-05-12"]],
    columns=["unique_id", "timestamp"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["A", "2019-01-05", "2019-02-02"],
    ["D", "2019-04-06", "2019-05-03"],
    ["C", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-05"],
    ["B", "2019-02-03", "2019-02-28"],
    ["E", "2019-05-04", "2019-05-31"],],
    columns=["classification", "from", "to"])

# Comparaison of different dataframes
print((df1['timestamp'] > df2['from']))
```

Error raised:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

**Here**, you want to compare according **the matching datetime interval**. So you need to distinguish the both dataframe. To convert string data to date, `pandas.to_datetime` do the job [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Here is one way to do:

```
# import modules
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, "2019-01-21"],
    [2, "2019-02-01"],
    [3, "2019-04-05"],
    [4, "2019-04-05"],
    [5, "2019-04-05"],
    [6, "2019-04-05"],
    [7, "2019-05-01"],
    [8, "2019-05-12"]],
    columns=["unique_id", "timestamp"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["A", "2019-01-05", "2019-02-02"],
    ["D", "2019-04-06", "2019-05-03"],
    ["C", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-05"],
    ["B", "2019-02-03", "2019-02-28"],
    ["E", "2019-05-04", "2019-05-31"],],
    columns=["classification", "from", "to"])

# convert to datetime
df1["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["timestamp"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df2[["from", "to"]] = df2[["from", "to"]].apply(pd.to_datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d")

# Try to compare 2 different dataframes
# print((df1['timestamp'] > df2['from']))

class_column = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    class_fd2 = df2[(df2["from"] <= row["timestamp"]) & (df2["to"] >= row["timestamp"])]["classification"].values[0]
    class_column.append(class_fd2)
df1["class1"] = class_column
print(df1)
#    unique_id  timestamp class1
# 0          1 2019-01-21      A
# 1          2 2019-02-01      A
# 2          3 2019-04-05      C
# 3          4 2019-04-05      C
# 4          5 2019-04-05      C
# 5          6 2019-04-05      C
# 6          7 2019-05-01      D
# 7          8 2019-05-12      E
```

You can also do it in a function to apply to `df1`:

```
def set_class(row):
    return df2[(df2["from"] <= row["timestamp"]) & (
        df2["to"] >= row["timestamp"])]["classification"].values[0]
# Process
df1["class2"] = df1.apply(set_class, axis=1)
print(df1)
#    unique_id  timestamp class1 class2
# 0          1 2019-01-21      A      A
# 1          2 2019-02-01      A      A
# 2          3 2019-04-05      C      C
# 3          4 2019-04-05      C      C
# 4          5 2019-04-05      C      C
# 5          6 2019-04-05      C      C
# 6          7 2019-05-01      D      D
# 7          8 2019-05-12      E      E
```

Comment: Thank you for simple and straightforward answer. This one worked like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

what i would personally do is convert timestamp to unix timestamp.

```
for row in df1['timestamp']:
    row = int(mktime(row.timetuple())
```

do the same for df2 to get your start and end timestamps and so then you can use the `df1.loc[(df1['timestamp'] > df2['from]) & (df1['timestamp'] < df2['to']), 'class'] = df2['classification']´` you wrote w/o getting error message

Answer (score 0):

try:
`import numpy as np`
now instead of
`df1['timestamp'] > df2['from]`
try:
`np.greater(df1['timestamp'],df2['from])`
looks like your are trying to get a true\false answer.
might want to take a look here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html